# How can I get a rounded border covering x% of div in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to make a progress div, it it a little ball with the percentage inside itself. It has a border and the border should cover only the amount of the percentage. Like the following example:

[image]

I want to know how to get this example doing it with css or javascript.

Comment: Please read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines in order to understand how to write a good question that might stand a better chance of receiving an answer.

Comment: see: http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/mLA7X/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach would be using SVG stroke.

1. create an SVG circle
2. set its stroke-dasharray to equal its circumference (2*Pi*radius)
3. dynamically change the stroke-dashoffset between 0 and stroke-dasharray to partially fill the pie

Here is the technique on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/#article-header-id-7)

And here is a simple [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/mike-shtil/pen/gXZajr) I made

[image]

```
<section>
  <svg>
    <circle></circle>
  </svg>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" value=".5"
        oninput="changeFraction(this.value)">
</section>

<style>
  body {
  background-color: gray; 
}

svg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 50px;
}

circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke: cyan ;
  stroke-width: 20px;

  /* interesting part */
  stroke-dasharray: 785px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 392.5px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
</style>

<script>
var circle = document.querySelector('circle');
var circ = 785; // circumference
function changeFraction(fr) {
  circle.style.setProperty('stroke-dashoffset', (1 - fr)*circ+'px');
}
</script>
```

Comment: maybe it just doesn't work in Firefox... There is only that slider, and moving it does nothing...

Comment: Now the circle is there, but it's a full circle, and moving the slider still does nothing... (BTW: I didn't downvote)

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which expect you to write code for them and make no attempt to do so on their own first. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob I'm curious though, without prior knowledge of this particular trick, how would the OP attempt a solution? Would them making a mock with solid borders or something help anyone?

Comment: I'll repeat what I posted in the comments under his question. On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself. It is a mistake to think of Stack Overflow the same as other sites and forums. In particular, read the "research" blue link.